# Google sites container with embedded url is not responsive

Tags: google-apps-script, mobile, responsive-design, google-sites

I'm trying to make a section on google sites with embedded code from google apps script. Even though app script is responsive, when I'll embed it to gSite container show scroll and cutting the content, like so:
[container with scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bZBN.png)

I was thinking to split the app scrips to separate ones and embed it to separate containers, but maybe there is different way.

Any ideas how to solve the problem? :)